# How to make MKMapView draggable with Image on top of it in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

A while ago in storyboard I've added MapView and placed ImageView, with disabled interaction, on top of it. I did it to show pointer to the center of the map with radius.
Now I want do the same but in SwiftUI. So I created ZStack and added MKMapView and Image. Obviously map area behind Image is not draggable. I tried `.allowsHitTesting(false)` but it did not help.
Tap works fine and goes down to the Button. But Drag does not reach MapView.

I've tried solution with MapViewOverlay and replace overlay every map move it is sort of fine as the solution. But still want to find out what am I missing with map and image solution.

Here is my sample code:

```
struct EditDestinationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Edit Destination")

            ZStack {
                Button("Tap Me") {
                    print("Button was tapped")
                }
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .background(Color.white)

                DestinationMapView(centerCoordinate: .constant(
                        CLLocationCoordinate2D()
                    )
                )
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.2))
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to it. Add image as UIView with disabled interaction as a subview to a MapView.
Example:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: DestinationMapView
        var circleAdded: Bool = false

        func mapViewWillStartRenderingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
            addCircle(mapView)
        }

        func addCircle(_ uiView: MKMapView) {
            if circleAdded == false && uiView.frame.size.height > 0 {
                let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "radius"))
                image.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                image.center = CGPoint(x: uiView.frame.size.width/2, y: uiView.frame.size.height/2)

                uiView.addSubview(image)
                circleAdded = true
            }
        }
}
```